# stopping variables from resetting on self call

Tags: php

In the following PHP code, I'm trying to generate a random number if its not already and store it in a variable called `$number`, also I'm taking user input and storing it in `$userInput`.

Every time the submit button is pressed , the same page is called again using `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`.

My problem is that I want the `$number` to keep its value once its set. no matter how many times the submit button is pressed, which is something that is not happening now.
the `$number` is set every time I press submit button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Number Guessing Game!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php 
            $userInput = $_POST['number'];
            if(!$number){
                 $number = rand(1, 500);
            }
            else{
                 echo "random number is $number <br>";
                 echo "you entered $userInput";
            }

            echo "<h3> $number </h3>"; //just to see if the number is changing everytime
       ?>
       <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>">
            <input type="text" name="number" /> <input type="submit" name="Submit"
            value="Submit" />
       </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make your random number persist betwen page views, you'll need to use sessions

http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php/

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way without using cookies or sessions is just to pass the value in an hidden field in your form.  When submit is pressed it will be passed across.

Use cookies/sessions if you want it to have the same value on returning to the page later on (i.e. closing the browser then reopening at a later stage).  Use the form hidden field if you only want it to persist when pressing the submit button.

Comment: That's also highly insecure, as the user will be able to tell what number you generated.Use with caution.

Comment: It's only insecure if this is something the user must not see.  Also if the number is used in any javascript etc then it will be plainly visible to the user anyway.

Comment: Either way, he has not stated that the number should be hidden from the user, therefore my method is perfectly valid and will ensure that the number is only persisted across form submissions. Which incidently is what he asked.

Comment: Correct, that's why I said "Use with caution" and didn't downvote.

Comment: @JonTaylor  Thanks for the answer,but yes, the user should not see the random number generated in any way!

Comment: In that case my method is not suitable, you should look at using sessions as described by some of the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to implement PHP sessions.
The number which you assign to $number is only accessible in the code that is called after it is set.

[W3Schools PHP Session tutorial](http://w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)

Hopefully the link will help you.

Cheers

Comment: Don't reference w3schools, their information is often misleading. See http://w3fools.com

Comment: I agree with you but in this case their information is correct.

Comment: Still, you will cause them to consider w3schools as a good site, which it's not. Even if there's one good apple up there, doesn't mean the rest of the tree isn't rotten.

Answer (score 1):

After php run's the script the variables are destroyed. Use cookies, seesions or sql for keeping the data over pages.